# How to make a string of some specific values in the dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-male ">:Before</i>
  <i class="fa fa-like">:Before</i>
</div>
```

Now I want to make a string like this: `male, like`. How can I do that?

---

```js
console.log(/fa-([^"]+)/.exec($('div').html()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <i class="fa fa-male ">:Before</i>
      <i class="fa fa-like">:Before</i>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You will need to loop after you select all icons. For example like this:

```js
var str = $('.fa').map(function() {
  return this.className.match(/fa-([^"]+)/)[1]
}).get()
.join(', ')
  
console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <i class="fa fa-male">:Before</i>
  <i class="fa fa-like">:Before</i>
</div>
```

Comment: This is much better than my answer, should use this once OP! nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the the elements using `map` and extract (replace) the class name of the element.

```js
var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('fa');

var str = Array.from(icons)
.map(c => c.classList.value.replace('fa fa-', ''))
.join(', ')

console.log(str)
```

```html
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-male">:Before</i>
  <i class="fa fa-like">:Before</i>
</div>
```

Comment: `replace('fa fa-', ''))` is not reliable, it will not work if class is `fa somasdf fa-ck`